# how to run script after user login but not for root

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i want to run a script for all user and new user after the login but not for root . 
I add my script on **/etc/profile.d** but unfortunathely. the script is executed for all users logged in but also for root and i dont want that .

Do you have an idea how i can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the [`EUID`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-EUID) in the script:

```
if [ ${EUID} -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Not running this script since you are root"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-eq` though?

Comment: @tripleee Right! I hope I didn't ruin the OP's computer! :)